# springMVC not able to locate the config directory

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

my springMVC project not able to locate the config directory

My application directory structure is--

myapplication

```
  +src/javaApplication

  +webcontent

        +web-inf
            +jsp
            +lib
        +config
```

while accessing this configuration I am getting an error

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [springsocial] in context with path [/socialmedia] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError] with root cause
java.util.NoSuchElementException: 'babelnet.minEdgeWeight' doesn't map to an existing object

I am trying to use babelnet in springMVC application. where should i put the configuration details in spring please suggest.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In general, your file hierarchy should probably be something like this:

```
/src
  /main
    /java
    /resources
    /webapp
      /WEB-INF
  /test
    /java
```

Configuration files that need be be on the classpath should go into the `/src/main/resources` directory.  Config files that you reference directly can go pretty much anywhere, but probably belong either in the `resources` folder or the `WEB-INF` folder, depending on the context of their use.  Spring MVC configuration files should go into `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`.

Comment: i had put the cofiguration inside resources.again after i am facing same problem. my application not able to detect the config folder.

Comment: If you edit your question and add your application-context.xml, dispatcher-servlet.xml and any other config files you have, it'll be easier to isolate the problem.